# How can I get the actual relative path using \import and \subimport?

Tags: pdftex, paths, svg, import

I have structured my PDFLaTeX document in folders. Inside them there are `.tex` files, `.PDF` figure files. And all works using `\import` and `\subimport` commands from the `Import` package:

```
Main/
 |-- main.tex
 |-- work.svg
 |-- Chapter1/  
      |-- body.tex
      |-- notwork.svg
      |-- figure.PDF
      |-- figure.SVG
```

So in `main.tex`:

```
...
\import{Chapter1/}{body.tex} %% OK
...
```

In `body.tex`:

```
...
\includegraphics{figure.PDF} %% OK (so relative path is working)
...
```

Now, I'd like to use SVG figures and InkScape and automate the process as explained in:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf

It uses `\pdffilemoddate` command in `\executeiffilenewer` called by `\includesvg`.

If I change in `body.tex`:

```
...
\includesvg{figure}
...
```

then `\executeiffilenewer` macro doesn't invoke InkScape because `\pdffilemoddate` can't find the file (if `figure.SVG` and `figure.PDF` are located in Main folder it works so it's a problem with the file path).

How can I handle this?

I think I need to access the actual path constructed by `\import` to modify `\executeiffilenewer`, but I don't know how.

## Working Example

You need 2 aditional SVG files (`work.SVG` and `notwork.SVG` located as in the tree above)

File `Main.TeX`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{minimal}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp
    {\pdffilemoddate{#1}}
    {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}
    >0
    {\immediate\write18{#3}}
  \fi%
}

\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{
  \executeiffilenewer{#1.svg}{#1.pdf}
    {inkscape -z -D --file=#1.svg --export-pdf=#1.pdf --export-latex --export-area-drawing}
  \import{}{#1.pdf_tex}
}

%% This is a not working try
\newcommand{\includepathsvg}[2]{
  \executeiffilenewer{#1#2.svg}{#1#2.pdf}
    {inkscape -z -D --file=#2.svg --export-pdf=#2.pdf --export-latex --export-area-drawing}
  \import{#1}{#2.pdf_tex}
}

\begin{document}

%% Delete all PDF figure files in Main and Chapter1 folder and uncomment some lines to test:

%SVG: \includesvg{work}
%SVG: \includesvg{Chapter1/notwork} %% InkScape invoked but notwork.pdf_tex can't find notwork.pdf because unknown relative path
%SVG: \includepathsvg{Chapter1/}{notwork} %% InkScape not invoked becaude \pdffilemoddate can't find notwork.svg

File Body.tex:

\import{Chapter1/}{body.TeX}

\end{document}
```

File `Body.TeX` in `Chapter1` folder:

```
%% Delete all PDF figure files in Main and Chapter1 folder and uncomment some lines to test:

%SVG: \includesvg{Chapter1/notwork} %% WORKS but I have to include the relative path 
%SVG: \includesvg{notwork} %% InkScape not invoked becaude \pdffilemoddate can't find notwork.svg
%SVG: \includepathsvg{Chapter1/}{notwork} %% Problem with path: Chapter1/notwork.svg when invoking InkScape
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem: working from snippets is a bit of a challenge.

Comment: I have found the macro `\input@path` in file `Import.STY`. I can view the relative path using: `\makeatletter \input@path \makeatother` but I can't use it into `\pdffilemoddate` to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have solved my problem. Here are the changes to do in the example:

```
\makeatletter
  \def\relativepath{\import@path}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
  \executeiffilenewer{\relativepath#1.svg}{\relativepath#1.pdf}%
     {inkscape -z -D --file=\relativepath#1.svg --export-pdf=\relativepath#1.pdf --export-latex --export-area-drawing}%
  \subimport{}{#1.pdf_tex}
}
```