# import input pgfplots with relative paths

Tags: pgfplots, include, filesystem-access

The package [import](http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf) makes it posible to `\input` (and `\include`) a `.tex` document which itself `\input` (or `\includegraphics` etc.) stuff using relative paths. I was hoping that this also would work with the `\addplot file` in `pgfplots`, but it does not. Is there a way to use relative paths in `pgfplots`?

---

**Failing example**: Place main.tex anywhere and edit path to `fig.tex`. - File `fig.tex`, `input.tex` and `plot.dat` in same directory. I can compile the standalone `fig.tex`, but `main.tex` can not find `plot.dat`.

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
mainMain
\import{\absolute\path\to\fig.tex}{fig.tex}
\end{document}
```

---

#### `fig.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\input{input.tex}  %this is ok
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot file {plot.dat};  %this is not working
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

#### `input.tex`

```
anything
```

---

#### `plot.dat`

```
1   2
```

---

Comment: This problem can be solved by the *currfile* package, at least partially. see [this question and answer by Jost](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215557/missing-folder-paths-in-tikz-picture-when-loaded-with-tikzscale-standalone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pgfplots processes input files line-by-line, a requirement which is impossible using `\input` or `\include`. Consequently, pgfplots uses `\read` (a low level TeX macro) for the job.

The requested feature is unsupported by pgfplots and would need to be implemented.

Note that while it is not programmatically supported by pgfplots, you could still modify the TEXINPUTS variable (i.e. the file search path used by TeX globally): this would also allow pgfplots to find your file. This is particularly simple on a unix system (does someone know if miktex also respects this variable?). The main idea here would be to set the environment variable to `/your/path:/your/other/path:` . Note the final colon (`:`): it tells TeX to append the system pathes at this location.

Comment: It would be be a nice thing, so please implement it. \begin{badJoke} You have my permission. \end{badJoke}

Comment: Thanks ;-)  . There are other pending feature requests (namely to support search paths programmatically). Wouldn't this also solve the problem?

Comment: Problem: Standalones with pgfplots can with relative paths be moved, copied and distributed:o) -but not inserted into other documents:o(

Comment: I do not know exactly what 'support search paths programmatically' means, but I hope it solves my problem.

Comment: The feature request "support search paths programmatically" involves some command like `\graphicspath{{/your/path}{/your/path2}}` which is defined in the preamble (pgfplots would use a different syntax). Any file input routine would then search through this path in order to find a match.

Comment: Implementing the "support search paths programmatically" feature would definitely improve my quality of life, so I give my moral support to it. Unfortunately I am unable to give actual coding support. :-(

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [this pgfplots' feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/45/), I found this old question. I once stumbled on this problem and found a solution (Unfortunately, I didn't documented where the solution came from, I guess not totally from myself). It's not exactly perfect but works. I define the following macro

```
\makeatletter
\def\relativepath{\import@path}
\makeatother
```

And use it every time I use a data file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\input{input.tex}  %this is ok
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot file {\relativepath plot.dat};  %this is not working
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It's not perfect, I don't like adding the `\relativepath` macro, It is an `import` solution and not `pgfplots` but it does the job.

### Edit

My solution dates back at least to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17361/how-can-i-get-the-actual-relative-path-using-import-and-subimport).