# Including a tikz figure with a reference to a table on file, problems with folder structure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, input, folders

I am trying to include a `tikz` figure in the chapter 6 of my thesis.
I am using separate folders and .tex files for each chapter, as you may notice in the example.
This means that in my main document I have the following code:

```
\input{H6}
```

Inside H6.tex, I have the following

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{./H6Figs/Eyeartable.tikz}
\end{figure}
```

The folder structure in a nutshell:

```
Main folder:
main.tex
H6.tex
  |
   --H6 (folder)
      Eyeartable.tikz
      Eyear.dat
```

The file Eyeartable.tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$Daily \; Energy \; [kWh]$},
xmin=-7, xmax=371,
ymin=-50, ymax=40,
axis on top,
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
xtick={0,59,120,181,243,304},
xticklabels={Jan 1,Mar 1,May 1,Jul 1,Sep 1,Nov 1},
legend entries={Consumed,Generated,Exchanged},
xticklabel style={anchor=north east,rotate=45}
]

\addplot[mark=none,color=blue] table[x index=0,y index=1,header=false] {"Eyear.dat"}; 
\addplot[mark=none,color=green!50.0!black] table[x index=0,y index=2,header=false] {"Eyear.dat"}; 
\addplot[mark=none,color=red] table[x index=0,y index=3,header=false] {"Eyear.dat"}; 


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This figure shows perfectly in `qtikz`, but when trying to compile it in my document I get:

> Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '"Eyear.dat"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `.dat` file in the present working directory of the `.tex` documents?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38412/import-input-pgfplots-with-relative-paths

Comment: Including H6Figs/ in the tikz file helps (although now it doesn't work anymore in qtikz, but I can live with that).
I actually tried it before but probably missed one Eyear.dat, throwing me of my trail.
Thanks for the help

Comment: This problem can be solved by the *currfile* package, at least partially. see [this question and answer by Jost](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215557/missing-folder-paths-in-tikz-picture-when-loaded-with-tikzscale-standalone)

Answer (score 2):

Namefiles are relative to the path of your main document, not to the path of the last input document. So you have to put your `.dat` file in the main folder, or to write the relative route `H6Figs/` before the filename in each `\addplot`.

Alternatively, you can set `TEXINPUTS=.//:` before compiling. This basically "flattens" all your directory tree at the eyes of latex. It is not advisable if files with the same name appear in different directories.