# How to map value to color using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I am trying to draw rectangles, each of which has a corresponding value, which will be mapped into a color from a color map based on the value.
This is how I want the write the code.
What is missing is the mapping from `\myvalue` to `\mycolor`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\newcommand*{\ListOfRectanglesColor}{%
  0/0/1/1/blue,
  1/1/2/2/red,
}

\newcommand*{\ListOfRectanglesValues}{%
  0/0/1/1/0.3,
  1/1/2/2/0.6,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \sXa/\sYa/\sXb/\sYb/\mycolor in \ListOfRectanglesColor {
    \fill[\mycolor] (\sXa, \sYa) rectangle (\sXb, \sYb);
  }
  %\foreach \sXa/\sYa/\sXb/\sYb/\myvalue in \ListOfRectanglesColor {
  %  what code will define \mycolor as a color based on \myvalue?
  %  and a specified color map?
  %  \fill[\mycolor] (\sXa, \sYa) rectangle (\sXb, \sYb);
  %}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edited in response to comment**

**Question:** How do I map values to colors?
I would appreciate it if the TeX code were commented so that I could understand how the code works.

For simplicity, the mapping function will be of the form

```
\valuetocolor{value-min}{value-max}{color-min}{color-max}{value}
```

The floating point numbers `value-min` and `value-max` will be mapped to two defined colors `color-min` and `color-max` respectively.
We can assume that `value-min` ≤ `value-max`.
I want to map the floating point number `value` to the linear interpolated value between `color-min` and `color-max`.
More precisely, let `λ` be the value such that `value = λ value-min + (1 - λ) value-max`.
Then I want `\valuetocolor{value-min}{value-max}{color-min}{color-max}{value}` to return the color `λ color-min + (1 - λ) color-max`.

---

**Related TeX.SX Question**

I am aware that there is a related question [Need some help getting started with TikZ, groupplots and color mapping of matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134114/need-some-help-getting-started-with-tikz-groupplots-and-color-mapping-of-matrix)
where there is TeX code that accomplishes a mapping from value to color for a more complicated color map.
Unfortunately, with my limited TeX/PGF knowledge, I can't understand how the code works.

Comment: What is the algorithm to determine the color in `\mycolor` based on a numerical `\myvalue`?

Comment: I've edited the question based on your comment to clarify how to mathematically determine the color.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\colorlet` macro from the `xcolor` package can define a mix between two colors (`color1` and `color2` in this example):

```
\colorlet{color1}{red}
\colorlet{color2}{blue}
\colorlet{my mixed color}{color1!\lambda!color2}
```

The `\lambda` value must be an integer between 0 (`my mixed color` is blue) and 100 (`my mixed color` is red).

By default, colors and mixing are in the RGB color space. If the two colors are in the HSB color space, the mixing is in HSB color space:

```
\colorlet{color1}[hsb]{red}
\colorlet{color2}[hsb]{blue}
\colorlet{my mixed color}[rgb]{color1!\lambda!color2}
```

Here is a simple example with two colormaps between `red` and `lime` (left in RGB color space, right in HSB color space) using values (`\myvalue`) between 0 (`\min`) and 20 (`\max`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \colorlet{color min rgb}[rgb]{red}
  \colorlet{color max rgb}[rgb]{lime}

  \colorlet{color min hsb}[hsb]{red}
  \colorlet{color max hsb}[hsb]{lime}

  \def\min{0}
  \def\max{20}

  \foreach \pos in {0,...,20}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myvalue{\pos}

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lambda{(\myvalue-\min)/(\max-\min)*100}
    \colorlet{my color rgb}[rgb]{color min rgb!\lambda!color max rgb}
    \colorlet{my color hsb}[rgb]{color min hsb!\lambda!color max hsb}

    \fill[fill=my color rgb,draw=white] (1cm,\pos cm) rectangle +(1cm,1cm);
    \fill[fill=my color hsb,draw=white] (2cm,\pos cm) rectangle +(1cm,1cm);
    \node at (3.5cm, \pos cm + 5mm) {\myvalue};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I like how your example illustrates the mixings for the two different color spaces, and the output demonstrates that the interpolation works correctly.