# Colour of edges according to edge value

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am currently modelling traffic and my map of roads consists of nodes connected with lines. For each road there is maximum capacity and amount of traffic and each road therefore has a utility value between 0 and 1.

To my question; I am wondering whether there is a colouring method for my lines in tikz that defines the colour by a value. For example I may want a high utility value to be red and a low utility level to be green and values in between are gradients of the booth. Is this possible in some way?

EDIT: The answer in the link is useful. I am now updating all my values to my lines manually; is there perhaps a way to retrieve them from a vector?

Comment: Did you read [How to map value to color using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159244/14500)

Comment: Yes thank you that solved it. Although I am now updating all my values to my lines manually; is there perhaps a way to retrieve them from a vector?

Comment: You may ask a new question or complete this one.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Seb any chance for an MWE?