# Missing folder paths in tikz picture when loaded with tikzscale/standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, standalone, tikzscale

I have a standalone `mytikz.tikz` picture which loads `test.png`. Both reside in the folder `pics/`.
My `main.tex`, which uses tikzscale to load `mytikz.tikz`, is in the parent folder.
Loading the `test.png` fails, when compiling `main.tex`, as the path is wrong. Somehow `main.tex` needs to know about the `pics/` path. How do I achieve this, while still keeping the `standalone` functionality?

A similar problem arises, if e.g. common color definitions are used, say in `pics/mycolors.tex`, which are then loaded in `mytikz.tikz` via `\input{mycolors.tex}`.

The matter is further complicated, when trying to plot data from a file in `pics/`. How do I convey the correct path name to `main.tex` in this case?

Contents of `main.tex`:

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pics/mytikz.tikz}
  \caption{includegraphics full width}
  \label{fig:tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Contents of `pics/mytikz.tikz`:

```
%mytikz.tikz
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

%\input{mycolors.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
    ]
    \addplot graphics [
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    ] {test.png};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just found out about `currfile`, but it is not working yet. Maybe someone can give an example for this?

Comment: You may use `\grapicspath` form graphics (see p.10 of grfguide.pdf).

Comment: Like adding `\graphicspath{pics/}` in `main.tex`? That does not work for me, same error of not finding `test.png`.

Comment: The correct syntax is `\graphicspath{{./}{pics/}}` (it is a list of paths).

Comment: That works nicely. However, what if I want to plot data from a file residing in `pics/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Manual inclusion of [currfile](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile)**

Simple addition of `\usepackage{currfile}` at the beginning of main and picture file, as described in `currfile`'s manual does not solve my problem.

I instead opted for manually adding `\currfiledir` whenever a relative path in some `pics\` folder is needed. This retains the advantages of a standalone picture, which can also be compiled from the main file.

There is a problem with common color definitions, which may reside in the parent folder. They have to be included in the standalone picture as well as when compiling the main file. I have solved this by checking for an empty `\parentfiledir`, in which case the file is loaded as I usually would from the `.tikz` file.

The result looks like this:

**Contents of `main.tex`:**

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{currfile}

\input{mycolors.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pics/mytikz.tikz}
  \caption{includegraphics full width}
  \label{fig:tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Contents of `pics/mytikz.tikz`:**

```
%mytikz.tikz
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{currfile}

\ifdef{\parentfiledir}{%if
}{%else
  \input{../mycolors.tex}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
    ]
    \addplot graphics [
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    ] {\currfiledir test.png};

    \addplot table [x index={0},y index={1}] {\currfiledir data.out};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```